# Aligning 1 Div above 3 more

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help with the CSS?

I can get the three columnar divs pretty easily, but can't figure out how to align a div above them the width of the three below.

I'd also like to align an image in a header row to the left most div below.

I am not at all a web developer; this is a landing page for something else I am working on.

Thanks!

[image]

```css
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .inner-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px; /* Add margin for spacing between the two rows */
  }

  .box {
    width: 300px; /* Adjust width as needed */
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <p>This is the first div.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seeing your current code will give a clear picture of how your page is structured. This is crucial for understanding how to integrate the new elements (the div above the three columnar divs and the image in the header row) without disrupting your existing layout.

Answer (score 1):

`subgrid` can do this.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container .header {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.inner-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}

.child {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child header">
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the container to flex direction column to stack your top box and bottom container (holding the 3 boxes) vertically

the top box naturally takes up the full width of its container

the bottom container uses display flex to lay out the boxes and uses space between to evenly distribute them.

run the code snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%; 
}

.top-box {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bottom-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* Distributes the column boxes evenly */
  gap: 10px; 
}

.column-box {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1; /* Allows boxes to grow and fill the container */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-box">
    <p>This is the top div that stretches across the entire width.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-container">
    <div class="column-box">Column 1</div>
    <div class="column-box">Column 2</div>
    <div class="column-box">Column 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A single flexbox with it's items each set to `flex: 1 1 auto` seems to work.

```css
.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  gap:12px;
}
.inner-container > div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height:64px;
  width:64px;
  outline: 2px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <p>This is the first div.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple grid layout of 3 columns and display set to contents for the inner container.

```css
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .container > :first-child {
    grid-column: span 3;       
  }
  .inner-container {
    display: contents
  }

  .box {
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <p>This is the first div.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  margin: auto;
}

.top-box {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bottom-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Distributes the column boxes evenly */
  gap: 10px;
}

.column-box {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height:160px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.minwidth {
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentContainer" style="width:100%">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" width="100" height="100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:flex">

    <div class="minwidth">
    </div>
    <div style="width:95%">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="top-box">
          <p>This is the top div that stretches across the entire width</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container">
          <div class="column-box">DIV 2</div>
          <div class="column-box">DIV 3</div>
          <div class="column-box">DIV 4</div>
          <div class="column-box">DIV 5</div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just restructured your HTML ELEMENTS and added some extra css